# OpenMP support in R and RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp

I struggle to enable OpenMP support for R in Ubuntu 16.04. When installing RcppArmadillo, OpenMP is 'found', but I get the following message when installing packages (e.g. 'forecast') that depend on RcppArmadillo:

```
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppArmadillo/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -
Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c 
calcBATS.cpp -o calcBATS.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo:53:0,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:46,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:31,
             from calcBATS.h:36,
             from calcBATS.cpp:1:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:474:96: 
note: #pragma message: WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler 
doesn't support OpenMP 3.0+
#pragma message ("WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler doesn't 
support OpenMP 3.0+")
```

My ~/.R/Makevars are the following:

```
VER=-5.4
CC=ccache gcc-$(VER)
CXX=ccache g++-$(VER)
FC=ccache gfortran
F77=ccache gfortran
CXX11 =ccache g++-$(VER)
CXX14=ccache g++-$(VER)
CXX_STD = CXX11

CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu11 -fopenmp
FCFLAGS=-O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu11 -fopenmp
CXXFLAGS   = -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu11 -fopenmp
CXX11FLAGS = -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu11 -fopenmp
CXX14FLAGS = -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu14  -fopenmp

PKG_CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp
PKG_CXXFLAGS= -fopenmp
PKG_LIBS = -fopenmp -lgomp

CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp
FCFLAGS=-O3 -g0 -Wall -pipe -fopenmp
```

I have played around with these settings, but nothing seems to help. Any wise thoughts would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Update:

I think some packages are using openMP now (e.g. xgboost). However, I still get the error message with some packages (e.g. Amelia):

```
* installing *source* package ‘Amelia’ ...
** package ‘Amelia’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppArmadillo/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -
Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c 
em.cpp -o em.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo:53:0,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:46,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:31,
             from em.h:3,
             from em.cpp:2:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:474:96: 
note: #pragma message: WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler 
doesn't support OpenMP 3.0+
#pragma message ("WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler doesn't 
support OpenMP 3.0+")

^
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o 
Amelia.so em.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -
lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Amelia/libs
```

I can see that Amelia does not finish with '-fopenmp' unlike xgboost, but I don't know what else to add to my ~/.R/Makevars. Installation of xgboost ends in the following (note the -fopenmp):

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-
z,relro -o xgboost.so ./xgboost_R.o ./xgboost_custom.o ./xgboost_assert.o 
./amalgamation/xgboost-all0.o ./amalgamation/dmlc-minimum0.o 
./rabit/src/engine_empty.o ./rabit/src/c_api.o -fopenmp -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xgboost/libs
```

Comment: The compilation you see is from the forecast package (on which demography depends). So I believe what matters may not be your makevars file, but the forecast package’s makevars. But hopefully someone who knows this better will come along.

Comment: Sorry, edited question. The same error is shown when installing forecast package.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @hejseb is correct.  (Rcpp)Armadillo now wants to use OpenMP when it can---on new enough compilers.

But *client* packages need to turn this on, meaning they have to change *their* file `src/Makevars` from having just

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

to

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

to enable OpenMP in *the client package* on both compilation and linking.
And e.g. the `forecast` package does not yet do that.

You can also set "global" `#define` in your `~/.R/Makevars` to skip OpenMP if you find this too noisy.  But you'd leave some performance on the table, which is not a good default.  Which is why (Rcpp)Armadillo makes the noisy comment.

*Edit:* There is one minor nuisance in that you need to set the flags *for every C++ dialect* so make sure you set `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, `CXX11FLAGS` and `CXX14FLAGS`. You should see the `-fopenmp` on the command-line when `R CMD INSTALL ...` does its work.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Does that mean that I can switch on OpenMP on already installed packages by changing their Makevars? There wouldn't happen to exist a list of all affected packages? I received a fairly long list of the affected packages, but I forgot to write them all down. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can also add it "globally" in `~/.R/Makevars`. It should not do harm: it just "offers" to build with OpenMP which many package will not use. But a few, like `forecast` will benefit.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had already added the global support in `~/.R/Makevars`.  What did I do wrong? Should I use your code above in `~/.R/Makevars`?

Comment: Made some edits to question. Still having the problem. Dirk, do you have any additional advice? Many thanks.

Comment: You may have missed my edit to my answer 9 hours ago.  "If you don't see it" then you haven't yet edited the right variable.

Comment: But I have edited the CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, CXX11FLAGS and CXX14FLAGS. See above

Comment: The `xgboost` line you quote is from LINKING and the linker needs another round.  Try `grep -i openmp /etc/R/Makeconf` (adjust path for your R's Makeconf, the above works on Debian + Ubuntu).

Comment: I get `admin@dlserver:~$ grep -i openmp /etc/R/Makeconf
DYLIB_LDFLAGS = -shared -fopenmp# $(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS)
MAIN_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS = -fopenmp`